# get text from nested span with bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to take the name "Felix Wong" from this:

`<span>Felix Wong <span class="drivers">+3 drivers</span></span>`

im using get_text but it returns full txt: "Felix Wong +3 drivers"

Comment: Your problem is not about html parsing, it's about string parsing. For that you need to use string functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) to get your goal and select by first index:

```
soup.select_one('span').contents[0]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span>Felix Wong <span class="drivers">+3 drivers</span></span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('span').contents[0].strip()
```